# Why combine np.floor function and the // operator in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikits

I am reading the source code of the library 'scikits-image' written in Python, I found the next line of code:

```
n_cellsx = int(np.floor(sx // cx))
```

I don't know why they join the NumPy function `floor` and the `//` operator. Is there any reason to do this? I can't see. I feel that is doing the same thing twice.

The project is [here](https://github.com/scikits-image/scikits-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/hog.py)

Comment: It looks like he really, really wants the result to be an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to do that, `//` will return either an integer or a float corresponding to an integer, so `floor` will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As for the why do the whole thing: They might want to cut a *given* number of following zeros... Check out this example:

```
>>> int(np.floor(40 // 10))
Out[40]: 4
```

if one just did int, then he would get 40....

As for why the int part,

```
>>> (49 // 10.0)
Out[50]: 4.0
```

The floor() part does nothing however, unless the code used to have / instead of //, or the programmer is afraid a colleague might substitute // with / ...